# On the fly field value calculation in Solr

Tags: solr

I've 10s of fileds defined in my Solr manaed-schema, out of those two are as below:

```
<field name="isBookmarked" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

<field name="bookmarkedPathologists" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Now, here I want to set `isBookmarked` value to `'true' OR'false'` if `bookmarkedPathologists` has SOME value passed while querying on the fly.

Post that I'm sorting on `isBookmarked` field.

Is it possible? Help anticipated

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the fact that `bookmarkedPathologists` has a value as your sorting criteria? Does it need to be stored in "isBookmarked"? If the latter case, create a update processor chain that adds a value for the isBookmarked field based on whether there's a value in bookmarkedPathologist, if the first, either use a regular sort, a filter query (to remove any rows with or without a value) or an `if` function as part of your sort criteria.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I'm new to Solr & latter I came to know about update processors. But my below posted answer, worked for me to fulfill my need.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot and finally got luck to solve my problem using below possible solution.
As on the fly updated changes need to be committed to Solr before getting sorted result on and hence my application which is Solr Client, couldn't get updated/dirty values to sort on, if any.

So I added a `Filter Query` to my `Simple Query` Criteria as `*  exists(query({!v='bookmarkedPathologists:patho'}))` : will filter my all(*) results with new on the fly created field named as **exists(query({!v='bookmarkedPathologists:patho'}))** in JSON response as below:-

```
    :
    :
    "isBookmarked": false,
    "bookmarkedPathologists": [
      "patho1"
    ],
    :
    :
    "_version_": 1582235372763480000,
    "exists(query({!v='bookmarkedPathologists:patho'}))": false
```

Post that I just put sort-order over the same i.e. **exists(query({!v='bookmarkedPathologists:patho'}))** as `exists(query({!v='bookmarkedPathologists:patho'})) asc`

So Solr returned sorted response over **exists(query({!v='bookmarkedPathologists:patho'}))**.

Solr Function Query helped me a lot from [Function Queries](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to update the field while querying the data from it.
SOLR programmed in java language and to interface with SOLR is done using REST kind of services.

And service for search is on:
`/solr/<CollectionName>/select`

And service for update is on:
`/solr/update`

So you can`t do both with using same query.
But you want to update externally (using other query) then [refer](https://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/).

Comment: Thanks for a response.